# Windows 10 RDP client crash when printing through RDP printer redirection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, printing, terminal-server, windows-10

We are deploying Windows 10 1607 across our company and we are currently having an issue with printers not redirecting over Remote Desktop to a Windows 2012 R2 server:

1. Printing crashes the RDP client.
2. The session remains disconnected on the Terminal Server.
3. The broken print job remains in the print queue.

Older clients (Windows 7) work fine with the same server.

[Disabling Easyprint](https://asithadesilva.wordpress.com/tag/disable-terminal-server-easy-print/) fixes the problem with Windows 10, but is not a complete solution: we have many different printer models from different vendors; we need to make EasyPrint work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this hotfix helps:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2916266

> Symptoms
>   When you print a large document from a Remote Desktop
>   Services (RDS) session by using the Easy Print feature in Windows 8.1,
>   Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1), or Windows
>   Server 2008 R2 SP1, the Mstsc.exe process crashes.

Also, make sure both the terminal server and the clients have all the latest updates installed.

Comment: Clients has all updates. The server is regularly updated and `systeminfo` provides a large list of updates, including the reason there is no 2955164. I'll try to install this patch to the next server maintenance window. Thanks.

Comment: 2955164 is for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2; you need to install 2916266 on the Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal server. It's a custom hotfix, thus you have to request it from the page by clicking on the "Hotfix download available" button.

Comment: But update [2955164](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2955164) includes 2916266. And it [available for Windows Server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42738). I am wrong?

Comment: If you are running Windows Server 2008 R2, you need to install hotfix 2916266; if you are running Windows Server 2012 R2, you need to install update 2955164. They solve the same issue but are packaged differently.

Comment: Thank you this is my typo. Of course I have 2012 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the printer driver is up to date on the client machine as you use a newer OS.

Keep in mind that some printer hardly support TS Easy print. (some thread like [there](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/TS-Easy-Print-amp-P1102W/td-p/785341) show it too)